# Swift OSX- View Loading Late (viewDidLoad) (applicationDidFinishLaunching)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, viewdidload, xcode13

Thanks for the help!

Whenever I enter any code after viewDidLoad or applicationDidFinishLaunching,  my view is delayed until after that code has finished. Also tried viewDidAppear.

*Not Using SwiftUI
*Running Big Sur Xcode 13.2.1

Let's say I've entered

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
sleep(5) }
```

The view will load after the sleep...  I know sleep isn't a great example, but I've tried it with many functions.

Also if I run any code in AppDelegate - in applicationDidFinishLaunching
Same Result.

Any Tips/ Help/ Updates are greatly appreciated!

Comment: These callbacks are all synchronous and on the main thread. You should only do essential, view-related work on them. Everything else you should push off onto a background queue.

Comment: Ahh.. Thanks! Learning more everyday.... Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DispatchQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue) to resolve that issue.

Run your code in another thread using your own queue or predetermined:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
        //your code here
        sleep(5)
    }
}
```

Comment: DospatchQueue worked for me with the code above ☝️ in Swift 5!

Comment: Thanks a bunch I spent hours trying to understand & you solved in minutes!